# Manage Multiple Activity, Resume Activity with Sub Activity instead Starting New

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a question. Refer to this:
[How to manage multiple Activity stacks in an Android app, like you would on iOS with multiple UINavigationControllers within a UITabBarController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614635/how-to-manage-multiple-activity-stacks-in-an-android-app-like-you-would-on-ios)

With this visualization:
[image]

From the image above:

1. I have 4 tabs with button view
2. Tab 1 pressed, activity appears. Go to another sub activities, then tab 3 pressed.
3. When tab 3 pressed, activity appears, then tab 1 pressed should resume previous sub activities.

Then my problem is :

When tab 1 is pressed, i always start activity without the previous sub activities within it.

Then how can I resume activity contains sub activities that already in stack?

Answer (score 0):

You should use fragments here inside tabs. Fragments stack are easy to manageable and lightweight process.